# Generating a loop to match ID's

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames, each containing identifiers.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(20001, 20001, 20003, 20003, 20003, 20003))
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(20001, 20001, 20003, 20003, 20003, 20005),
                  Type = c('N1', 'N2', 'N3', 'N4', 'N5', 'N6'))
```

I would like to create a second column in df1 with the values of df2$Type by matching the ID's. This is my usual method for looking up values

```
df1$Add <- df2$Type[match(df1$ID, df2$ID)]
```

However, using this matching method will obtain the first ID match and bring over the corresponding value giving me something like this

```
ID     Add
20001  N1
20001  N1
20003  N3
20003  N3
20003  N3
20003  N3
```

Instead I'd like to bring over the 'next' type value for every repeated ID, essentially on a loop. Ideally I'd like to following output.

```
ID     Add
20001  N1
20001  N2
20003  N3
20003  N4
20003  N5
20003  N3
```

I assume it will require some use of lapply with possibly a user defined function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate(c = rep(df2$Type[df2$ID == unique(ID)], length.out = n()))

#     ID      c
#1 20001     N1
#2 20001     N2
#3 20003     N3
#4 20003     N4
#5 20003     N5
#6 20003     N3
```

---

```
# incase of efficiency, 

library(data.table)
setDT(df2)
setDT(df1)[,  x := rep(df2$Type[df2$ID == ID], length.out = .N),by = .(ID)]
```

---

```
# i'm looking for a base R solution without involving merge
# as of now my bet is on sapply() - but not utilised efficiently

unlist(sapply(unique(df1$ID), function(x) rep(df2$Type[df2$ID == x],
                                              length.out = sum(x==df1$ID))))
# [1] N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 N3
```

Comment: I went with the dplyr solution, since it has already been loaded for a previous chunk of code. Great use of mutate, thanks for the help.